# Why is the following code extremely slow?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT gs.HomeTeamId, 
100*avg(s.P2M)/avg(s.P2A) as P2P FROM gamesstats as gs, stats as s 
WHERE gs.LeagueId = '145' AND 
gs.SeasonStart = '2010' 
GROUP BY gs.HomeTeamId 
HAVING P2P > 52.12765958
```

That is the SQL I try to ask for on my mysql server. For some reason it takes too much time. I can separately get `s.P2M` and `s.P2A` in a second, but this takes forever.
Anyone sees why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by using `FROM gamesstats as gs, stats as s` without a join in a where clause you're effectively creating a cross join between 2 tables. add a joining condition.

Comment: You can do a WHERE instead of join, which I found that I didn't a minute ago. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You have no join condition between gamesstats and stats.  So you're creating a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) which could be billions of rows in size.

Comment: You can do a WHERE instead of join, which I found that I didn't a minute ago. Thanks anyway.

Comment: That's logically the same thing as a join.